# Gain vs ADC performance vs ADC settling time

Tags: microcontroller, adc, analog, gain

I have some basic doubts in ADC conversion. I am using AD7798 ADC. I am reading ADC values using AT90USB1287 micro controller using SPI communication. I am able to read ADC values perfectly but i have some doubts.

I had gone through the datasheet several times. I am setting Configuration register as "0x0230" and mode register as "0x0009". It means update rate as 16.7Hz and gain from "4 to 128".

When i try to read ADC value with 16.7Hz update rate it is taking more time but accurate values.

I would like to get values more fast than present time so i changed update rate from 16.7 Hz to 232Hz. Now ADC reading values more faster but not accurate.

How can i read ADC values more accurate and faster? Changing gain will effect ADC update rate?

Could anyone give me some explanation regarding Gain Vs Update rate vs accuracy?

From the datasheet i see that gain will effect on resolution and update rate will effect on signal to noise ration.

[AD7798datasheet](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD7798_7799.pdf)

Comment: At 16.7Hz sampling the internal filters will reject 50Hz and 60Hz. Above this the internal filters don't operate so maybe you are picking up AC power frequencies. Try averaging a bunch of readings that are sampled at a multiple of 16.7Hz to see if the numbers come good. Then try averaging a number of samples that is half way between multiples of 16.7Hz to see if the numbers are again bad.

Comment: You've demonstrated that speed and accuracy are generally inversely correlated. What makes you think this isn't an intrinsic feature of most ADCs (hint- it is)?

Answer (score 2):

"How can i read ADC values more accurate AND faster?" You can not. They are inversely correlated in delta-sigma ADCs. Read how a delta-sigma ADC works [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt423/slyt423.pdf)

But you can take some measures to improve SNR characteristic of your circuit by:
1- Following the design guidelines in your ADC data sheet, in particular Grounding and Layout section.
2- Add appropriate filtering in your input stage.
3- Some general guidelines, like using linear power supplies rather than switching if possible, having separate analog and digital ground planes on your PCB, etc.